# Angular 6 installation

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to Angular and trying to run `"npm install -g @angular/cli"` after installing node and npm. On execution of this command getting error:

```
"npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})"
```

After that `ng` command is not recognized.

Node version is 8.11.1 and npm version is 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

`fs-events` is optional and not relevant on Windows platforms.

If you want to skip it:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

Seems like this is a common issue (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042) with no good solution, other than ignoring it or skipping it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however after running this command getting registry issue